# Web Service Passing Object Error

Tags: java, web-services

I'm trying to pass `List<Object>` using web service, the list came in Hibernate Criteria Search.

My Criteria Search code is:

```
public class SeacrhUsers {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session ses  = Connection.Connection.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria cr = ses.createCriteria(DB.Vehicles.class);
        List prof = cr.list();
        //System.out.println(prof.size());
        hello(prof);
    }

    private static java.util.List<java.lang.Object> hello(java.util.List<java.lang.Object> user) {
        Task.NewWebService_Service service = new Task.NewWebService_Service();
        Task.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        return port.hello(user);
    }
}
```

I get this Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class DB.Vehicles nor any of its super class is known to this context.
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class DB.Vehicles nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:424)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:192)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:144)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:225)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.hello(Unknown Source)
>       at Model.SeacrhUsers.hello(SeacrhUsers.java:31)
>       at Model.SeacrhUsers.main(SeacrhUsers.java:25)
>   Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

How can this be resolved? Any suggestions.

Comment: Please show the definition of the of the class that "user" represents.  It has to have JAXB annotations.  You can't just pass any old POJO in.